# Solution for a problem using vectors in c++ shows   when submitted but runs fine when the same input is run using custom input

Tags: c++, vector, error-handling, runtime-error, out-of-memory

Recently I was solving this problem on **interviewbit.com** - https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/merge-intervals/.

I solved the problem using vectors and performing operations on vectors

Here is my code:

```
    vector<Interval> Solution::insert(vector<Interval> &intervals, Interval newInterval)
    {

    int n=intervals.size(),leftfound=0,rightfound=0,count=0;
    if(n==0)                  //for the case when intervals vector is empty
       {  
        intervals.push_back(newInterval);
        return intervals;   
       }

    int t=0;
    if(newInterval.end<newInterval.start)   //if(start>end) swap
       { 
        t=newInterval.start;
        newInterval.start=newInterval.end;
        newInterval.end=t;
       }
    if(newInterval.start>intervals[n-1].end) //if the newInterval succedes every other
       {
        intervals.insert(intervals.end(),newInterval);
        return intervals;
       }
    if(newInterval.end<intervals[0].start)//if the newInterval precedes every other element
       {
        intervals.insert(intervals.begin(),newInterval);
        return intervals;
       }

    auto left=intervals.begin(),right=intervals.begin(); //just initialising with something
    auto it=intervals.begin() ; // iterator for loops

    while((*it).start<newInterval.start&&it!=intervals.end()) //*it is dereferencing the iterator to 
        it++;         //get the element of vector "intervals" at that index

    it--; // decrementing it to reach the desired interval

    if((*it).start<=newInterval.start&&(*it).end>=newInterval.start)
       {
        leftfound=1;left=it;
       }
    else 
        left=it+1;

    it=left;

    while((*it).end<newInterval.end&&it!=intervals.end())
        it++;

    if((*it).start<=newInterval.end&&(*it).end>=newInterval.end)
       { 
        rightfound=1; right=it;
       }
    else 
        right=it-1;


    if(right-left==-1&&leftfound==0&&rightfound==0)// this if will be true in cases like:
        intervals.insert(left,newInterval);          //intervals=[(1,2),(8,10)] and newInterval=(4,6)
    else        //in every other case this else will execute
       {   
        if(leftfound==0)
        (*left).start=newInterval.start;
        if(rightfound==0)
        (*left).end=newInterval.end;
        else (*left).end=(*right).end;
       }
    left=left+1;

    intervals.erase(left,right+1);
    return intervals;
}
```

The interviewbit.com platform(IDE) requires to only complete the function given as mentioned in the problem.

> NOTE: You only need to implement the given function. Do not read input, instead use the arguments to the function. Do not print the output, instead return values as specified. Still have a doubt? Checkout Sample Codes for more details.

I need to implement this:

`vector<Interval> Solution::insert(vector<Interval> &intervals, Interval newInterval) { }`

Also the Interval structure is defined as :

```
struct Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
    Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};
```

Now this solution runs fine when tested using the test button on the site. After that when I press submit it shows the following error:
[click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG1Um.png). When I run the same test case (for which the error was encountered) using custom input the code runs fine and gives the expected output. I can't seem to find what the problem is. I suspect it might be because of the erase function since in the error it shows `free()`, but I am not even remotely sure.

Also, I ran the code on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/wWjqV4) adding the structure and main function in the code and it runs absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
intervals.insert(left,newInterval);
```

`std::vector::insert` invalidates all existing iterators to the contents of the vector. Immediately afterwards:

```
left=left+1;

intervals.erase(left,right+1);
```

The `left` and `right` iterators, to the same vector, are no longer valid at this point, and using them is undefined behavior.

This may or may not be the only bug in the shown code. The broken indentation makes the shown code hard to read and follow; but this is one definite bug in the shown code, that's likely the reason for the undefined behavior, and the crash.

Comment: I took your suggestion and fixed the indentation

Comment: I tried to understand your answer and made some sense of it since i am not that good and i have these follow ups and doubts :  https://pastebin.com/GtCkqm61

Comment: Which part of "std::vector::insert invalidates all existing iterators" you're unclear about? There's nothing complicated about this. After `insert()`ing into a vector you cannot use any existing iterators to the vector, because they are no longer valid. That's it. Nothing more than that. The shown code continues to use them, hence the likely crash.

Comment: okay i get it . now please open this pastebin.com/GtCkqm61 . i have doubts and don't worry they are not because i dont understand your answer